# Select results where price is not max price

Tags: sql, max

I have this table

```
ProductId       ProductName Category        Price
      1            Tiger      Beer          $12.00
      2             ABC       Beer          $13.99
      3            Anchor     Beer          $9.00
      4            Apolo      Wine          $10.88
      5           Randonal    Wine          $18.90
      6            Wisky      Wine          $30.19
      7             Coca     Beverage       $2.00
      8            Sting     Beverage       $5.00
      9             Spy      Beverage       $4.00
     10           Angkor      Beer          $12.88
```

How to select all results except that with max price 
Max price is $30.19

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?  You should attempt your homework yourself before getting the result.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What's the expected result if there are two products with the same highest price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below

```
select * from tablename where price not in 
  (select max(price) from tablename)
```

Comment: Why `not in` if the subquery will only return one row exactly?

Comment: yes @GolezTrol agreed with u sir - but in time of answering this is one thing came in my mind .. thank u

Answer (score 2):

You can query the highest price like so:

```
select max(Price) from Products; -- Assuming 'Products' is your table name
```

You can then embed that query in another query to get all products that have a lower price than that:

```
select
  *
from
  Products
where
  Price < (select max(Price) from Products)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with operator and using max function.

```
Select * from Prices where Price < (select max(Price) from Prices)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `max` as windows analytical function :

```
select q.ProductId, q.ProductName, q.Category, q.Price
  from
  (
   select t.*,
          max(t.price) over (order by t.price desc) max_price
     from t
   ) q   
 where q.price < max_price;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/AFMS55639)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename where price not in 
  (select max(price) from tablename)
```